# Is there an error in this attempt at a counter-example to the thrackle conjecture?

Tags: graph-theory, conjectures

I spent some time today thinking about [Conway's thrackle conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrackle#Thrackle_conjecture). After a while, I came up with [this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynsK4.jpg), which looks to me like a counter-example. I'd assume there's an error in there that I've missed. I'd appreciate it if you could take a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a thrackle:

> A thrackle is an embedding of a graph in the plane, such that each edge is a Jordan arc and every pair of edges meet exactly once. **Edges may either meet at a common endpoint, or, if they have no endpoints in common, at a point in their interiors.**

*(Emphasis mine.)* Shared endpoints count as meets in this context! In your graph, the top vertex has four edges coming out of it - the top two meet twice (at the shared vertext and at the crossing at the bottom of the graph) and the bottom two also meet twice (at the shared vertex and at the crossing directly below).